# Can not find image path in web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I am using asp.net mvc 4.0 application.
I am using II7/II8. 
I have configured my web application under following way in IIS in following way

```
Default Web Site\MyWebApp
```

When I am trying to browser my page in local machine
http://localhost/Home in that following image is rendered. This image is surely available at /Content/Images/ but not loaded properly, when in browser I do inspect element and alter the path like /MyWebApp/Content/Images/ it is loading an image properly.

```
<img alt="close" style="cursor: pointer;" src="/Content/Images/ic-delete.png" onclick="closePopUp('dvclose');">
```

While in live server IIS , I have website like www.xxx.yzx and when I am trying to browse 
www.xxx.yzx/home it is loading image properly

i am trying to do somthing so I don't want to bother to change path(remove MyWebApp) of image when I am deplying. I don't want to move my application from Default We Site

What to do for loading image in local machine?

Comment: ~/Content/Images/ic-delete.png 

Try that as the src.

Comment: Awesome. Posted my comment as the answer for anyone else that comes along. and so this is question is marked that it has an answer

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment as the answer:

~/Content/Images/ic-delete.png Try that as the src.